# images won't display after retrieving file location from SQL table using php

Tags: php, mysql, html, image, directory

Each row in the SQL table represents a user. There are 5 columns related to images: image1, image2, image3, image4, and image5. columns image[1-5] represent the image file directories. All the image columns are of the "text" type.

The problem is that when I type in the directory it will display but using the row variable will not work. For example, `echo '<img src= "images/img1.jpg" /> ';` will display the picture but `echo '<img src= "$row[image1]" /> ';` where `$row['image1'] = "images/img1.jpg"` will not work and I will see a torn page icon instead of a picture.

Here is the form script:

```
<form action="dbpform.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">



<input type="text" name="url"><br>

 <input name="uploadedfile1" type="file" /><br />
  <input name="uploadedfile2" type="file" /><br />
   <input name="uploadedfile3" type="file" /><br />
    <input name="uploadedfile4" type="file" /><br />
     <input name="uploadedfile5" type="file" /><br />

<textarea name="comment" id="comment" cols="55" rows="7" wrap="VIRTUAL"></textarea><br>

<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">


</form>

<?php
mysql_connect ("","","") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db ("") or die(mysql_error());

$url = $_POST['url'];
$comment = $_POST['comment'];

$target_path1 = "images/";
$target_path1 = $target_path1 . basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile1']['name']); 

$target_path2 = "images/";
$target_path2 = $target_path2 . basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile2']['name']); 

$target_path3 = "images/";
$target_path3 = $target_path3 . basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile3']['name']); 

$target_path4 = "images/";
$target_path4 = $target_path4 . basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile4']['name']); 

$target_path5 = "images/";
$target_path5 = $target_path5 . basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile5']['name']); 


if ( isset( $_POST['submit'] ) )
{   

move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile1']['tmp_name'], $target_path1);
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile2']['tmp_name'], $target_path2);
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile3']['tmp_name'], $target_path3);
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile4']['tmp_name'], $target_path4);
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile5']['tmp_name'], $target_path5);


mysql_query ("INSERT INTO dbp VALUES ('','$url', '$target_path1', '$target_path2','$target_path3','$target_path4','$target_path5','$comment')");            
}

?>
```

Here is the output script:

```
<?php

mysql_connect ("","","") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db ("") or die(mysql_error());



$defaultqry = mysql_query ("SELECT * FROM dbp");

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($defaultqry))
{


echo $row['comment'];


echo '<img src= "$row[image1]" /> ';
echo '<img src= "$row[image2]" /> ';
echo '<img src= "$row[image3]" /> ';
echo '<img src= "$row[image4]" /> ';
echo '<img src= "$row[image5]" /> ';


echo "<br><br>";


}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've left out some quotation marks.  It's interpreting the image1 in $row[image1] as a constant, probably generating an error message, which is causing your image to show up as not available.

Try something like this:

```
echo '<img src= "'.$row['image1'].'" /> ';
echo '<img src= "'.$row['image2'].'" /> ';
echo '<img src= "'.$row['image3'].'" /> ';
echo '<img src= "'.$row['image4'].'" /> ';
echo '<img src= "'.$row['image5'].'" /> ';
```

Comment: Or better yet just use double quotes for echo and single quotes for variables without any concat stuff - echo "<img src=\"$row['image5']\" /> ";

Comment: That will work too.  My personal preference is not to include variables in strings, I'm always forgetting backslashes and such, and using concatenation, syntax highlighting in my editor of choice highlights the variables correctly.